# Why did changing my target framework from ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".NET framework 4" give me warning messages?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xsd, app-config

The line:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
```

was added to my App.config file and now i get the warning messages:

> Could not find schema information for the element 'supportedRuntime'
>
> Could not find schema information for the attribute 'version'
>
> Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'

Can I just delete that line from the config file?  Everything works fine when I run the app.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is designed to target the Client Profile, you should setup your app.Config to match.  If you want to target the full .NET Framework, make sure to change your project type in the project settings window of Visual Studio to .NET 4 Framework.

Comment: I do need to target the full profile. I made the change so that I could access a method in the System.Web.dll. Where is the project settings window? What do you mean change the project type? The project is a console application.

Comment: In the solution explorer, look for the project.  Right click, and choose "Properties" - It'll open up the project window, where you can set the framework target.

Comment: Yes, that is what caused the problem in the first place. I changed the target framework in order to be able to reference System.Web. Wasn't it clear from my question that I changed the target framework? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this line. From the error messages, it sounds like there is a previous line in your app.config which has errors or is unclosed, or that this line was moved from it's correct place.
This is copied from a working project:

```
<configuration>

 <!-- Other configuration -->

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. There was no similar line before I changed the target profile. The file only contains a single database connection string. I did just notice the following: Before changing the framework I had: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> Now I have <?xml version="1.0"?>. Again, this change to the file was not something I did manually. Should I change it back?  Also note, if I delete the line, the warnings go away.

Comment: The project that i have here only has `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. I'm not sure what effect removing the line will have.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  I gave up on this.  I reverted the config file back to the way it was before the IDE changed it, and everything worked fine.  I still have no idea why MS wanted to add the "SupportedRuntime...." stuff to the config, but it seems unnecessary.

Comment: I have the sample problem and I can't get the warnings to go away.

Answer (score 1):

These lines are not required. I needed to write a console application to use asp.net membership provider. System.web was not available with client profile. So i changed to .Net framework 4. I removed these lines, it gave me no issues. 
    
Not sure why is it needed at first place.